# Add buttons on particular tab

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I would like to add button to particular tab in python frame, but unfortunately it is added to frame not tab. How to improve this?

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *


class Example(Frame):
def __init__(self, parent):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)


def main():
root = Tk()
root.geometry("450x300+300+100")


notebook = Notebook(root)

p1=notebook.add(Frame(width=450, height=300),text="Add")
p2=notebook.add(Frame(width=450, height=300),text="Show)
p3=notebook.add(Frame(width=450, height=300),text="select")

b = Button(p1, text="OK")
b.pack()

b2=Button(p2, text="No")
b2.pack()

notebook.pack()
root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent attribute is what defines where the button goes. You'll need to save a reference to each frame, and then use that as the parent for the button. Note: `notebook.add(...)` does *not* return a reference to the tab itself.

```
tab1 = Frame(...)
p1 = notebook.add(tab1, ...
b = Button(tab1, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand this.